# Use different WHERE clause based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to implement in a WHERE clause to filter on different condition based on certain scenario.

For example this is my `table2`:

```
MainID     TempID
-----------------
NULL        123
```

What I am trying to do is prioritize on filtering using `MainID` from `table2`. If `MainID` from `table2` `IS NOT NULL`, then filter using

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table1 
WHERE MainID = ...
```

But if `MainID` from `table2` `IS NULL`, then filter using

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table1 
WHERE TempID = ...
```

I thought of trying to use an OR, but I don't know if OR would always check based on the order left to right within the statement. I want to prioritize filtering based on the value from `MainID` from table2, but if it's not there then I need to filter on `TempID` from table2 based on a different column name within `table1`, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table1 
WHERE MainID = value OR TempID = value
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table1 WHERE MainID = value OR (MainID IS NULL AND TempID = value);`

Comment: No.  To make sure MainID gets prioritised you can add `ORDER BY MainID DESC`

Comment: You need to add more sample data to show a more realistic example, and cover edge cases.

Comment: Incase you *didn't* know, SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for nearly **5 years**; it is long past time you implemented that finalised upgrade plan you (hopefully) finalised back in 2017.

Comment: This would be one of those times when it would be really convenient if SQL Server had a `NULLS LAST` feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ISNULL` to get either the first ID, or if it's null then the second.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.Id = ISNULL(t2.MainID, t2.TempID)
    ORDER BY t1.SomeColumn
) t1;
```

If you didn't need `TOP 1` then you can use a normal join on `ISNULL`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.Id = ISNULL(t2.MainID, t2.TempID);
```